# select replace query taking too long in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to avoid special characters and spaces when update in SQL Server
I have a question about SQL Server: how to update target table flag using source table flag in SQL Server based on id and address columns.

When comparing id and address time (source and target tables), we need to consider only character and numbers data only.

While updating time, only consider characters and numbers only no need to consider any spaces or special characters.

Example: source table :

```
id | address            | Flag
1  | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1
```

Target table :

```
id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 |
```

I want to update target table's Flag using source table id + address.

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 700NCAptJ1w02 so Flag will be updated in target table Flag is :1 similar to others

Output is : target table :

```
id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1
```

in target table we need to updated only Flag column only.

Another example:

Source table :

```
id     |  address              | Flag
4      | 116 E Spence St #B    | 0
```

Target table :

```
id     | address                                      | Flag 
4      | 11 6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B NULL  |
```

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 116ESpenceStB

Table output record is :

```
id     | address                                          | Flag 
4      | 11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B    NULL  | 0
```

Sample table data with script is :

```
 ---source table : 
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourcemp]
    (
        [id] [int] NULL,
        [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [Flag] [int] NULL
    ) 

    ----Target table: we need update flag value using source table
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[targetemp]
    (
        [id] [int] NULL,
        [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
        [Flag] [int] NULL
    ) 

    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'700 N. C Apt# J1w02', 1)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'7010 N COLTON', 0)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'0923 E 55th ten-332', 0)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'9717 E. 6TH AE #32', 0)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'5704 E Chattaroy Rd', 1)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'hen@ye   yte&t#100', 0)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'2903 E. Euclid, Apt. #40', 3)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3', 1)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*(antic   STE 2000', 2)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'2706 W. College Ave.', 1)
    GO
I have a question about SQL Server: how to update target table flag using source table flag in SQL Server based on id and address columns.

When comparing id and address time (source and target tables), we need to consider only character and numbers data only.

While updating time, only consider characters and numbers only no need to consider any spaces or special characters.

Example: source table :

id | address            | Flag
1  | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1
Target table :

id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 
I want to update target table's Flag using source table id + address.

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 700NCAptJ1w02 so Flag will be updated in target table Flag is :1 similar to others

Output is : target table :

id  | address            | Flag
1   | 700 N. C Apt J1w02 | 1 
in target table we need to updated only Flag column only.

Another example:

Source table :

id     |  address              | Flag
4      | 116 E Spence St #B    | 0
Target table :

id     | address                                      | Flag 
4      | 11 6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B NULL  |

Source table address and target table address are same when we are not considering spaces and special character and address is 116ESpenceStB

Table output record is :

id     | address                                          | Flag 
4      | 11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B    NULL  | 0
Sample table data with script is :

---source table : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourcemp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Flag] [int] NULL
) 

----Target table: we need update flag value using source table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[targetemp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Flag] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'700 N. C Apt# J1w02', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'7010 N COLTON', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'0923 E 55th ten-332', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'9717 E. 6TH AE #32', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'5704 E Chattaroy Rd', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'hen@ye   yte&t#100', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'2903 E. Euclid, Apt. #40', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*(antic   STE 2000', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'2706 W. College Ave.', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourcemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'116 E Spence St #B', 0)

GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'700 N. C Apt   J1w02', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'7010 N COLTON.', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'0923 E 55th ten-332', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (1, N'971%7    E. 6TH AE #32', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'5704 E        Chattaroy Rd', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'henye   yte&t100', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (2, N'2903 E. !Euclid, Apt. #40', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (3, N'c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*anticSTE 2000', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'2706 WCollege Ave.', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[targetemp] ([id], [address], [Flag]) VALUES (4, N'11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B', NULL)
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below :

```
id  |address                                    Flag
1   |700 N. C Apt   J1w02                           | 1
1   |7010 N COLTON.                                 |0
1   |0923 E 55th ten-332                            |0
1   |971%7    E. 6TH AE #32                         |0
2   |5704 E        Chattaroy Rd                 |1
2   |henye   yte&t100                           |0
2   |2903 E. !Euclid, Apt. #40                  |3
3   |327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3                  |1
3   |c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*anticSTE 2000          |2
4   |2706 WCollege Ave.                         |1
4   |11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B    |0
```

I tried like below

```
update target   set target.flag=source.flag
from   targetemp target  join sourcemp source 
 on  target.id=source.id
and 
--and 
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( 
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace
 ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( 
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace 
( replace( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
(source.address,' ',''),'~',''),'`',''),'!',''),'@',''),'!',''),'#',''),'$','')
,'%','') ,'^',''),'&',''),'*',''),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),'_',''),'=',''),'+','')
,
',',''),'.',''),'/',''),'\',''),'<',''),'>',''),'?',''),'"',''),'''',''),':',''),';','')
,'{',''),'}',''),'[',''),']',''),'\',''),'|','')=
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( 
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace
 ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( 
replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( replace 
( replace( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
(target.address,' ',''),'~',''),'`',''),'!',''),'@',''),'!',''),'#',''),'$','')
,'%','') ,'^',''),'&',''),'*',''),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),'_',''),'=',''),'+','')
,
',',''),'.',''),'/',''),'\',''),'<',''),'>',''),'?',''),'"',''),'''',''),':',''),';','')
,'{',''),'}',''),'[',''),']',''),'\',''),'|','')
```

Above query is  taking tooo long since 11 hours  still is running.
Please tell me how to write the query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of easiest approaches. But performance will depend on your tables sizes and length of `address` column. Another option is to use tally table.

```
with rcte as (
    select
        id, address, flag, ln = len(address), step = 1
        , res = cast(case when substring(address, 1, 1) like '[0-9a-z]' then substring(address, 1, 1) else '' end as varchar(200))
    from 
        sourcemp
    union all
    select
        id, address, flag, ln, step + 1
        , cast(res + case when substring(address, step + 1, 1) like '[0-9a-z]' then substring(address, step + 1, 1) else '' end as varchar(200))
    from
        rcte
    where
        step < ln 
)
, rcte2 as (
    select
        id, address, ln = len(address), step = 1
        , res = cast(case when substring(address, 1, 1) like '[0-9a-z]' then substring(address, 1, 1) else '' end as varchar(200))
    from 
        targetemp
    union all
    select
        id, address, ln, step + 1
        , cast(res + case when substring(address, step + 1, 1) like '[0-9a-z]' then substring(address, step + 1, 1) else '' end as varchar(200))
    from
        rcte2
    where
        step < ln 
)
, cte as (
    select
        a.id, a.address, b.Flag
    from
        rcte2 a
        join rcte b on a.id = b.id and a.res = b.res
    where
        a.ln = a.step
        and b.ln = b.step
)
update a
set
    a.Flag = b.Flag
from
    targetemp a
    join cte b on a.id = b.id and a.address = b.address
```

Output:

```
id  addresss                                  flag
-------------------------------------------------
1   700 N. C Apt   J1w02                      1
1   7010 N COLTON.                            0
1   0923 E 55th ten-332                       0
1   971%7    E. 6TH AE #32                    0
2   5704 E        Chattaroy Rd                1
2   henye   yte&t100                          0
2   2903 E. !Euclid, Apt. #40                 3
3   327 1/2 W. 2nd Ave RM SP3                 1
3   c/o DC!FS   1313 N. Atl*anticSTE 2000     2
4   2706 WCollege Ave.                        1
4   11  6 E Sp  enc     e             St #B   0
```